# discriminant in PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

http://www.mscs.dal.ca/~iron/math5220/testsol.pdf

I was reviewing this site and for #2, does it look like there is a typo? I am not getting that same discriminant, and a little unclear on the sketch. Can someone please explain it?

Comment: The discriminant of the PDE $$Au_{xx}+2Bu_{xy}+Cu_{yy}=0$$ is $B^2-AC$, so I don't think there's any mistake. NB the convention in use here that the coefficient of $u_{xy}$ is written as $2B$.